# Сравнение строки с меняющимся параметром int

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, compare

Есть строка вида 

`/user/%d/view/`

Как на javascript понять что какая-то строка имеет такой вид?
Пример кода:

```
if (func(location.pathname) === func("/user/%d/view/")) {
   // do smth
}
```

Comment: var requiredStr = '/user/%d/view/';
var someStr = 'какая-то строка';
if (someStr.indexOf(requiredStr) !== -1) { console.log('yes') } 
Так?

Comment: @RobertDampilon, неужели только я подумал, что `%d` - это произвольное целое число?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит использовать [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) - создано для проверки по регулярному выражению.

```js
// Представим что %d - это int из printf
['/user/Aid/view/', '/user/207618/view', '/user/:)/view/'].forEach(str => {
  console.info(`Str: '${str}': test: ${/^\/user\/\d+\/view\/?$/.test(str)}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Привет. Тут нужно использовать regex

Что-то типа

```
var reg_exp = /user\/(.+?)\/view/g;
var isFound = reg_exp.test("/user/%d/view/")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (location.pathname.match(/^\/user\/\d+\/view\/$/))
```

Comment: @Qwerty, Вы абсолютно верно уловили идею с `location.pathname`. Вопрос: Ваша регулярка учитывает вариант с '/' на конце? Просто, правда, не силен я в них. Методом тестов: не учитывает. Это условие можно пихнуть в регулярку?

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, ворнинг: учитывает. Если нет - давайте пример, где это не учитывается.

Comment: @Aid `/user/3/view` вернет null.  По крайней мере, в консоли хрома возвращает

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, Эмм... Так Вам же с слешем надо, а Вы без слеша проверяете. Можно сделать необязательную проверку (будет совпадать с ним и без него), поправил ответ.

Comment: @Aid, космос. Я просто был готов руками проверять на этот слэш, поэтому в вопросе жестко не указал. Но коль @Qwerty явно заподозрил, что я манипулирую с `location.pathname`, понадеялся, что он и это предусмотрел. Вам спасибо:)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, все поняли про `location` (или проверка ссылок из массива), но в сниппет `location` другой.